# Problems using screenmanager in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I want to connect to screens but I don't know what i am doing wrong. I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work it keeps on showing the same error, I want to connect mainpagescreen to Nav_pageScreen but it keeps on showing the same error

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


Window.size = (1200, 800)

KV ='''
ScreenManager: 
    MainpageScreen:
    Nav_pageScreen:
<MainpageScreen>:
        name:"Mainpage"
    
        
        
                  
        
        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                icon: "code-braces"
                text: "Credits"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 120/255, 81/255, 169/255, 1
                line_color: 120/255, 81/255, 169/255, 1
                icon_color: 120/255, 81/255, 169/255, 1
                pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1} 
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: "Start!"
                id_bg_color: 0,0,0,0
                text_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2} 
                size_hint:(0.4,0.1)
                on_press:root.manager.current:"Nav_page"
                
            
        
<Nav_pageScreen>:
        name: "Nav_page"
        
        MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
            icon: "code-braces"
            text: "Credits"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 120/255, 81/255, 169/255, 1
            line_color: 120/255, 81/255, 169/255, 1
            icon_color: 120/255, 81/255, 169/255, 1
            pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1} 
            on_press:root.manager.current:"Mainpage"
            
'''

class MainpageScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Nav_pageScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MainpageScreen(name="Mainpage"))
sm.add_widget(Nav_pageScreen(name="Nav_page"))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

```
enter code File "/Users/Neil/PycharmProjects/Kivy_start/kivy_venv/kivy/main2.py", line 76, in <module>
 MainApp().run()
```

File "/Users/Neil/PycharmProjects/Kivy_start/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 949, in run
self._run_prepare()
File "/Users/Neil/PycharmProjects/Kivy_start/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 919, in *run_prepare
root = self.build()
File "/Users/Neil/PycharmProjects/Kivy_start/kivy_venv/kivy/main2.py", line 72, in build
kv = Builder.load_string(KV)
File "/Users/Neil/PycharmProjects/Kivy_start/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 373, in load_string
parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
File "/Users/Neil/PycharmProjects/Kivy_start/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 402, in **init**
self.parse(content)
File "/Users/Neil/PycharmProjects/Kivy_start/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 511, in parse
objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
File "/Users/Neil/PycharmProjects/Kivy_start/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 674, in parse_level
if current_property[:3] == 'on*':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code

Blockquote

Comment: I think your indentation in your `KV` is bad. You started with 4 space indentation, but after `<MainpageScreen>:` you changed to a larger indentation. That won't work. You must be consistent with the indentation.

Comment: @john Anderson but will it solve my error?

Comment: Give it a try. See if it does.

Comment: Oh thank you it worked!